# get json data from datatables row column wise

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatables

I have Datatable like bellow

```
<table id="example" class="display" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
```

On a button click I write bellow code

```
console.log(JSON.stringify($('#example').dataTable().fnGetData()))
```

above code returns bellow JSON

```
[["Tiger Nixon","System Architect","Edinburgh","61","2011/04/25","$320,800"],["Garrett Winters","Accountant","Tokyo","63","2011/07/25","$170,750"],["Ashton Cox","Junior Technical Author","San Francisco","66","2009/01/12","$86,000"]]
```

but I want this Row -Column wise like

```
["Name":"Tiger Nixon","Position":"System Architect","Office":"Edinburgh","Age":"61","Start date":"2011/04/25","Salary":"$320,800"]
```

How do I get data above format ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a remapping function to create an array that contains objects with properties and values:

```
var rawData = [
    ["Tiger Nixon","System Architect","Edinburgh","61","2011/04/25","$320,800"],
    ["Garrett Winters","Accountant","Tokyo","63","2011/07/25","$170,750"],
    ["Ashton Cox","Junior Technical Author","San Francisco","66","2009/01/12","$86,000"]
];
var template = ['Name', 'Position', 'Office', 'Age', 'Start date', 'Sallary'];

function mapData(data, template) {
    remapped = []
    for (subArray in data) {
        remappedSubArray = []
        for (element in data[subArray]) {
            remappedSubArray[template[element]] = data[subArray][element]
        }
        remapped.push(remappedSubArray);
    }

    return remapped;
}


remapped = mapData(rawData, template);

console.log(remapped[1]['Name']); // will output Garrett Winters
```

Comment: Is there any datatable's inbuilt function?

Answer (score 0):

`fnGetData` is deprecated, but still usable.

You can get the headers with `$('#example').dataTable().api().columns().header()`.

So you could build a function like so:

```
function getRCData() {
 oTable = $('#example').dataTable();
 var api = oTable.api();
 var header = api.columns().header();
 var data = oTable.fnGetData();
 var results = [];   

 for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
    results.push({});
    for (var j=0;j<data[0].length;j++) {
        results[i][header[j].innerText] = data[i][j];
    }
 }   

 return JSON.stringify(results);   
}
```